# MariaDB/MySQL RANK() implementation

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, rank

I am working on migration from MS SQL Server to **MariaDB 10.0**. I have query which use RANK() PARTITION BY. I already created some kind of RANK() implementation on my table but it's not working properly.

**The original query was:**

```
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY visits.id_partner ORDER BY visits.updated_at DESC) AS rank
```

**My implementation for MariaDB/MySQL:**

```
SELECT
    ...,
    (
        CASE visits.id_partner
            WHEN @currId THEN
                @curRow := @curRow + 1
            ELSE
                @curRow := 1 AND @currId := visits.id_partner
        END
    ) AS rank
FROM
    records rec
    JOIN visits ON visits.id = rec.id_visit,
    (
        SELECT
        @curRank := 0,
        @currId := NULL
    ) r
WHERE
    ...
ORDER BY visits.id_partner ASC, visits.updated_at DESC
```

I want to select row ranked by id_partner order by updated_at field. When id_partner is same as on row before RANK should increase by 1. When is different than before, it should reset to 1.

But my query is not working at all. I have still rank 1 on all rows. Can you help me find mistake?

Thank you for help!

Comment: How come the MS SQL Server tag? (Don't tag products not involved...)

Comment: I am so sorry, probably miss-click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is tricky to use variables in MySQL/MariaDB.  A variable should only be used and assigned in one statement (as you do correctly).  However, `AND` can short-circuit variable assignment.

I use a construct like this for `ROW_NUMBER()`.  `RANK()` is actually a bit of a pain . . . `DENSE_RANK()` and `ROW_NUMBER()` are simpler.  However, this seems to be the code that you are aiming for:

```
SELECT ...,
       (@rn := if(@currId = visits.id_partner, @rn + 1,
                  if(@currId := visits.id_partner, 1, 1)
                 )
       ) as rank
FROM records rec JOIN
     visits
     ON visits.id = rec.id_visit CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @rn := 0, @currId := NULL) params
WHERE
    ...
ORDER BY visits.id_partner ASC, visits.updated_at DESC;
```

EDIT:

In MySQL (and presumably in MariaDB), sometimes variables don't work quite right unless you use a subquery.  So, try this:

```
SELECT . . .,
       (@rn := if(@currId = visits.id_partner, @rn + 1,
                  if(@currId := visits.id_partner, 1, 1)
                 )
       ) as rank
FROM (SELECT ...
      FROM records rec JOIN
           visits
           ON visits.id = rec.id_visit 
      WHERE
          ...
      ORDER BY visits.id_partner ASC, visits.updated_at DESC
     ) t CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @rn := 0, @currId := NULL) params;
```

Comment: I have tried to rewrite query like you said, but I have still same result